# quiero hacer un post con express que suba imagenes en la ruta /images/:id pero ¿porque images.js no funciona?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

En esta imagen pueden ver que quiero hacer click en el Link change image y que me mande a la ruta `/images/new`, al hacer click a ese boton la ruta cambia pero la vista no, es decir no me aparece el formulario para subir la imagen, por eso asumo que algo falla en express en `images.js` aquí una muestra de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando `axios` para hacer los llamados a get, post, put etc...
pero el problema es que la vista no carga cuando cambio la ruta.

```js
const { Image, validate } = require("../models/image");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const admin = require("../middleware/admin");
const validateObjectId = require("../middleware/validateObjectId");
const moment = require("moment");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, image, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/img')
  },
  filename: (req, image, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + image.originalname )
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('image');

router.post('/', [auth], async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const image = new Image({
    image: req.body.image,
    publishDate: moment().toJSON()
  });
  
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
   
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
          return res.status(500).json(err)
        // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
      } else if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json(err)
        // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
      } 
      
      return res.status(200).send(req.image)
      // Everything went fine.
    });

    await image.save();

    res.send(image);
});

router.put("/:id", [auth], async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const image = await Image.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      image: req.body.image
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  if (!image)
    return res.status(404).send("The image with the given ID was not found.");

  res.send(image);
});

router.get("/:id", validateObjectId, async (req, res) => {
  const image = await Movie.findById(req.params.id).select("-__v");

  if (!image)
    return res.status(404).send("The image with the given ID was not found.");

  res.send(image);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que cuando haga click en el boton lila "change image" la vista del formulario para cargar la imagen aparesca, la tengo como componente se llama UploadImage y esta en mis rutas.

Aqui esta el archivo de rutas:

```js
import React from 'react';
import  { Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import Movies from './components/movies';
import MovieForm from './components/movieForm';
import UploadImages from './components/uploadImages';
import Customers from './components/customers';
import Posters from './components/posters';
import NotFound from './components/notFound';
import NavBar from './components/navBar';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import LoginForm from './components/loginForm';
import RegisterForm from './components/registerForm';
import './App.css';
import './assets/css/template.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ToastContainer />
      <NavBar />
      <main className = "container">
          <Switch>
          <Route path = "/register" component = {RegisterForm} />
          <Route path = "/login" component = {LoginForm} />
          <Route path = "/movies/:id" component = {MovieForm} />
          <Route path = "/movies" component = {Movies} />
          <Route path = "/customers" component = {Customers} />
          <Route path = "/images" component = {Posters} />
          <Route path = "/images/:id" component = {UploadImages} />
          <Route path = "/not-found" component = {NotFound} />
          <Redirect from = "/" exact to = "/movies" />
          <Redirect to = "not-found" />
          </Switch>
      </main>
      <Footer />
   </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Y el archivo de rutas?

Comment: @gbianchi ya agregue el archivo de rutas, al hacer click al boton la ruta si cambia pero la vista no.

Comment: Inverti el orden de las rutas. Pone primero images/:id... si funciona como pienso el problema esta ahi

Comment: si @gbianchi gracias era eso, ahora voy a trabajar en el backend, muchas gracias!! un abrazo :D

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que la nueva ruta `/images/:id` coincide en parte con la ruta anterior `/images/`, y te debe estar mostrando el componente `UplodaImages` justo después del contenido de `Posters` para evitar eso basta con que incluyas `exact` antes de path para que solo se muestre en el caso de coincidencia exacta.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar exact a tu ruta /images/:id y así no te choca con tu ruta /images/.

Aquí tienes la documentación que te puede ayudar

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Saludos

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)